# Requiring Admin Previleges to Change Proxy Settings

Tags: windows-7, proxy, uac

I have installed a Squid server to allow a whitelist-only internet access to my employees. All of them are using Standard User accounts in Windows 7 Professional.

I changed the proxy settings in their PCs to the Squid server, and everything works as expected.

Now if one of them types "proxy" in the search bar he will be able to disable the proxy and no Admin password will be required like in changing the static IP address or the default gateway.

How to add changing the proxy settings to the admin level to require admin previleges to this section?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the right way would be to block connections going to the internet directly, so by changing the proxy they will have no connection anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Using Group Policy (or local computer policy if you aren't on a domain) you can disable access to the connections panel completely and so prevent user access to the proxy settings :

Computer Configuration – Administrative Templates – Windows Components - Internet Explorer – Internet Control Panel - Disable the Connections page.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found this and it's doing what I just wanted:
https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/85238-internet-options-add-remove-connections-tab.html